# Loading a XIB from external Bundle - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsbundle

I am in need of loading a XIB file from a bundle. I am integrating with an external static library that shares with me a .bundle. Now, this .bundle has a XIB folder which contains MyView.xib file.

I am trying with below code:

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSURL *fileURL = [frameworkBundle URLForResource: @"External" withExtension:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:fileURL];

self = [self initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:bundle];
```

This code leads to crash.

During debug, I found that I get correct `frameworkBundle` handle and its loaded as well but while `bundle` handle is correct, I see a message "Not Loaded Yet" next to it.

Anyone have any idea as to how to tackle this?

Comment: Is the "external static library" yours? As in, can you modify it if necessary? Not sure if this will solve it for your specific case, but probably worth a look: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Comment: Also this SO question (which is where I found the other link): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571366/how-to-add-xib-file-in-static-library-in-ios

Comment: Yes, I have control on the static library.