# unable to access .nib(XIB) files from a framework in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios5

i have created a framework out of my existing code base and tried using it in a new code base. This worked fine. But my application is getting crashed when i try to access the nib files which is a part of my framework bundle. This is the code i am using to access the view controllers XIB file.

`testViewController *controller = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"testViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];`

The app is getting crashed without generating any error or crash report. Here aremy questions

**1 - Can we add xib files in our framework**

**2 - If, yes, what is the correct way to add and access the nib(xib)files from a framawork**(currently i have added them in the "*compile sources*" section of my "*build phases*" tab in "*build settings*")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write the name of the bundle in which you nib. files are store so change your above code to ...

```
testViewController *controller = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"testViewController" bundle:yourBundle]; [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

here your bundle is an object of type NSBundle. refer the [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for more info

Comment: testViewController *controller = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"testViewController" bundle:@"FI"]; [self.view addSubview:controller.view]; I modified the code like this ankit. Here FI is the name of my newly created bundle/framework. But even now my app crashes with the the following error. "[__NSCFConstantString pathForResource:ofType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6185c"... Any ideas

Comment: you dont need to give a string here.. see what apple has to say.. "- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle" it needs to be an object of type NSBundle.

Comment: But there is a catch here ankit, all my nib files are in a framework. How can i refer them from a bundle perspective?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question earlier.As far as I know you can't add .xib to static libraries, and personal frameworks are not supported by ios  , you can get more info here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707429/can-you-reference-xib-files-from-static-libraries-on-the-iphonelook at the second answer there by justicle.

Comment: +1 for a good link.... i did exactly as specified in that link.. but, still no luck.. The crash still persists... :(

Comment: do you wish to ship it to a client or for personal use.? In case personal then just put the .xib in your resources folder manually. Even I failed at this , when I tried it earlier around 6 months ago.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5768/discussion-between-a-for-alpha-and-ankit-srivastava)

Comment: @i_raqz there is no work around for this. You will have to ship your bundle and static library separately. so the user will have to include both in his/her project

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava... thank you for answering..even i am trying the same approach..but then running into issues of loading images...can you please help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695506/accessing-images-from-nsbundle

Answer (score 1):

In swift 2 - For storyboard :

```
let bundle = NSBundle(identifier:"com.bundileName.Name")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Storyboard", bundle:bundle!)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerId") as UIViewController
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For XIB:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(identifier:"com.bundileName.Name")
    if !(bundle == nil){
        let objtestViewController = testViewController(nibName: "testViewController", bundle: bundle)
        presentViewController(objtestViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Swift 3**
Storyboard:

```
 let bundle = Bundle(identifier:"com.bundileName.Name")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Storyboard", bundle:bundle!)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerId") as UIViewController
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Xib

```
let bundle = NSBundle(identifier:"com.bundileName.Name")
if !(bundle == nil){
    let objtestViewController = testViewController(nibName: "testViewController", bundle: bundle)
    present(objtestViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here bundle name is the bundle id of framework.