# Accessing images from nsbundle

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsbundle

I have a framework which is trying to access xib's and images from a bundle. I am able to access the xib fine but unable to load the images in UIImageView. I even check if the file exists and the console output is yes...

Any idea how to load the image?

Code to load xib in the framework viewcontroller file

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle" ofType:@"bundle"]]];
```

Code to load images

```
- (void) loadImage
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle.bundle/test" ofType:@"png"];
    BOOL present = NO;
    present = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
    if (present)
    {
        NSLog(@"MyBundle.bundle/test exists");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"MyBundle.bundle/test does not exists");

    }

    self.testImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:path];

    self.testImageView2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

> MyTestHarnessApp[11671:c07] MyBundle.bundle/test exists

Answer (score 4):

When you use `imageNamed:` you must pass just a simple filename and the image must exist in the root of the app's resource bundle.

Your image is not in the root of the resource bundle, it is in a subfolder.

Since you have obtained the image's full path in the `path` variable, you must use the `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` method:

```
self.testImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: tried your approach..doesnt work... 
MyBundle.bundle is another bundle in which the images are present...2

Comment: Which didn't work? Using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` or using the alternate way to get the path from the bundle? Using your path with `imageWithContentsOfFile:` should have worked.

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"MyBundle.bundle"];    self.testImageView2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

I tried this... it didnt work...

Comment: No, that's not what I suggested. Use your original code to get the `path`. That worked as shown by calling `fileExistsAtPath:`. All you need to do is replace `imageNamed:path` with `imageWithContentsOfFile:path`.

Comment: oops.... i tried as you suggested.. it didnt work...i hope you read the very first few lines of the question... "I have a framework which is trying to access xib's and images from a bundle"

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle.bundle/test" ofType:@"png"];
    self.testImageView2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: No where in your question do you mention the use of `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. The code you posted is using `imageNamed:`.

Comment: no no.. i meant... there is possibly a problem in framework-bundle image accessing in Xcode/iOS.... because i use the way you suggested in other places where the i am using one project as a dependent project of another and it works fine...

Answer (score 2):

If `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` isn't resolving the path correctly, you could always use:

```
self.testImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

Comment: There is no such method as `UIImage imageWithContentsOfPath:`.

Comment: See, this is why not to type methods out from memory. That should have been +[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile]. Auto-correct is really making my memory suffer.

Comment: Hmm ... well, I have been able to reproduce the problem that imageNamed: doesn't return the image correctly, but imageWithContentsOfFile: does create an image correctly in my test app - have you tried checking that a) the image is valid (does it work if its not in the bundle), and b) have you checked the name specified is correct including case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following:

```
self.testImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBundle.bundle/test.png"];
```

But it seems that if you put the XIB in the bundle too, the interface will be relative to the bundle.

```
self.testImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try going step by step.

First get the path to the bundle within your main bundle:

```
NSString *myBundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:MyBundle ofType:@"bundle"];
```

Check to see if there is anything in the bundle.  This is more for double checking.  Once it is working you can choose to omit this code.  But it is always a good idea to double check things.

```
 NSBundle *imageBundle=[NSBundle bundleWithPath: myBundlePath];
 NSArray *allImageURLs=[imageBundle URLsForResourcesWithExtension:@"png" subdirectory:nil];
 NSLog(@"imageURLS:  %@",allImageURLS);
```

Since you already have the bundle path add the image name to the path.  Or you can just pull it from the list of urls that you already have in the above code.

```
NSString *myImagePath=[myBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
NSLog(@"myImagePath=%@",myImagePath);
```

Then, since you have the full path, load the image

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImagePath];
```

Code taken from shipping app.

Good Luck

Tim

Answer (score 0):

If the images are already in the main bundle just use the image name: test.png or simply test

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
```