# How to get a resource or nib file from within a user framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, nib, nsbundle

How would you call a nib file from within a framework, say:

```
myFramework/Resources/a.nib
```

I have the framework built (with iOS-Universal-Framework MK from kstenerud) and installed in the test app, but can't seem to find a way to reference the nib file directly.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BarViewController_iPhone" ofType:@"nib"]
returns nil.

barViewController = [[BarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BarViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]; also does not work.
```

where the nib file name is `BarViewController_iPhone.nib`. It returns `nil`.

I also tried to reference my framework with `[NSBundle bundleIdentifier]`, but my framework has a null id. How do I set the id when I build the framework?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: his question here should answer yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707429/can-you-reference-xib-files-from-static-libraries-on-the-iphone

Comment: @Sebastian Flückiger: you should add your comment as an answer so this question can be answered/closed. The link is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting comment as answer:

For this question already exists a thread, that contains a lot of useful information & answers to this problem.

Read about it here: [Can you reference Xib files from static libraries on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707429/can-you-reference-xib-files-from-static-libraries-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Sebastian, Thanks for answering! I have read through that post and a couple others, and started on the path of using the framework. But I still can't seem to reference the resource file after my framework is built and included. Would the resource file of a included framework be in the main bundle or in its separate bundle?

Comment: it would be in the framework bundle =)

its explained greatly on this article: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000064.php

you need to fetch the nib from the frameworks bundle =)