# How to load nibs from static library to main project?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have made one static library which contains some nibs. When I try to load those nib files, I am getting **Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle**. If anyone knows how to do this, it will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: can you post your code? How did you invoke xib file?

Comment: [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:vcObj animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: code to load nibs is right but they are not getting linked or not getting referred by main project...

Comment: yes, &  how did you initialize your "vcObj"?

Comment: vcObj=[[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
vcObj.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

Comment: Read this,
[Can we reference Xib files from static libraries][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707429/can-you-reference-xib-files-from-static-libraries-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existed answer : [Can you reference Xib files from static libraries on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707429/can-you-reference-xib-files-from-static-libraries-on-the-iphone)

No you can't use this way,

A static library is a file that contains classes. It does not contain other files, it is essentially a database of compiled code.Even it is possible to put the data for the xibs in static library,But Xcode won't recognize that it was in there.

Answer (score 0):

when you allocate your controller init it with nib from main bundle.

[initWithNibName:@"Your nib.." bundle:[NsBundle MainBundle]]

Comment: tried...still same...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting linked or not getting referred by main project, then checkout following steps once, & make sure that You are not missing anything

1. Go to your xib (i.e. MyViewController)

   1. Open File Inspector
   2. Select File's Owner
   3. Select 3rd tab from File's Inspector
   4. Go into Custom Class section
   5. Check the class name

Comment: names is correct...still getting that error...